Migrating sensor plugin to gzsim harmonic
I have migrated a custom sensor plugin based on ray sensor (from gazebo classic) to a system plugin based on GPU lidar (gzsim - harmonic).
How can I convert this Load() method to gzsim?
void MyCustomSensor::Load(gazebo::sensors::SensorPtr _parent, sdf::ElementPtr _sdf) {
    ray_sensor_ = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<gazebo::sensors::RaySensor>(_parent);

    if (!ray_sensor_) {
        gzthrow("This plugin requires a Ray Sensor as its parent");
    }

    initComNode();

    connection_ = ray_sensor_->LaserShape()->ConnectNewLaserScans(
        std::bind(&MyCustomSensor::onNewScans, this));
}

